# Old Kivy Label doesn't disappear on updating text property

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing a clock application (will eventually run on Raspberry Pi, but developing on Windows), and whenever a label updates the changed characters are drawn on top of the old ones, but the old one doesn't disappear.

It looks like this.

[image]

Here's my code:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivy.config import Config

import time

class RPiClock(BoxLayout):
    timeString = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RPiClock, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.timeString = str(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"))


class RPiClockApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')
        appWindow = RPiClock()
        Clock.schedule_interval(appWindow.update, 1)
        return appWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RPiClockApp().run()
```

RPiClock.kv:

```
<RPiClock>
  Label:
    id: TimeLabel
    text: root.timeString
    font_size: '50sp'
```

What's causing these graphics to stick around?

Comment: I have tried it in Linux and it works correctly, maybe it is a problem of the opengl that you use, I recommend reporting it as a bug to kivy.

Comment: I think I've seen this come up before as a graphics driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, try adding a colored canvas in the background -- in your case I would likely use a black rectangle that fills up your layout. It may solve your problem (it did for me).